# Alternative for KendoUI in Angular 4

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, bootstrap-4

I am working on a project using:

1. Web API 2
2. Angular 4

I want to choose a framework for GUI. I thought about "Telerik KendoUI for Angular" which is really a good lib. But Bootstrap 4 is the only version whose supported from this version of Kendo. My company has a design made in Bootstrap 3, so they don't want to change it.

The question is: is there any other Lib for GUI like KendoUI we can use them? 
or is there a tool or something to convert a file from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4?
Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are plenty of other UI component libraries available for angular.

primeng
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/

vmware
https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation

ngSemantic
https://ng-semantic.herokuapp.com/

You can find a list of other UI components here as well:
https://angular.io/resources/